# Find documents older than x months with mongodb in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to query the documents older than X months in mongodb. I do not have an explicit creation date field, and I do not have permission to.

I have tried to use the CreationTime property of the Mongo ObjectId, but I get the exception
`System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the serialization information for f => f.Id.CreationTime.`

I made a function to do the query:

```
public async Task<int> GetReportCountXmonths(string name, int months)
{
    await GetCollection<Clients>()
        .Find(Builders<Clients>.Filter.Eq(d => d.name, name) 
            & Builders<Clients>.Filter.Gte(f => f.Id.CreationTime, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-(months))))
        .CountDocumentsAsync();
}
```

**Question:** how do I find the documents older than X months in a MongoDB collection, using C#?

Comment: check with the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't keep track of created date of a collection. However, it's really easy to do this yourself. Add a createddate field in mongdb collection. 
Another way is to use objectId which implies timestamp,but it is not a consistent way.

If you really want to use objectId. Convert your corresponding date into objectId
and query using this objectId with the collection objectId.

```
 var sampledate=new Date("requireddate");
 var testobjectId =Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000).toString(16) +"0000000000000000"; 
  db.comments.find({_id: {$gt:testobjectId }})  ;
```

Convert the above method into c#.

Comment: If it was just for a single document I would have no issue, but as you can see then I am getting a set, all that matches. I do not understand how I can apply what you suggest in my query.

Comment: Query like this "var filter = Builders<Clients>.Filter.Gt("_id", testobjectId );"

Comment: Your idea seems to have merit, but  I have failed to figure out how to manually construct an ObjectId via google. Since I do not know what language your code is from I can't guess why you divide by 1000 or need to add so many zeros..

Comment: You have to create an objectId in c# corresponding to your date.The above code is in javascript. You will easily get alternative code in c#.

Comment: Actually mongodb is using this algorithm for creating objectId for the collection

Comment: You'd think so, but when I check the date component after creating an ObjectId it is wildly off!.  I ended up doing this, which is not working correctly: `ObjectId.Parse(Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Ticks / 1000, 16) + "00000000000")`

Comment: var cticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            var jticks = (cticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000;
            var testobjectId = Convert.ToString(jsticks / 1000, 16) + "0000000000000000";  Use the testobjectId  for query

Comment: @Jeppe You have to convert the C# ticks into javascript ticks .Try the above code

Comment: There is a difference?! Javascript never ceases to horrify me!
But luckily all this trial and error finally let me step back and find the solution:
`new ObjectId(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-(months)), 0, 1, 2)`

Comment: I can :) So much work just because I hadn't seen the ObjectId constructor -_-

Comment: And I just realized that this time the ticks issues actually is MS fault, their DateTime objects do not follow the generally accepted Unix standard

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer with a lot of help from @Thaks!

I needed to compare directly against the id, and not the CreationTime property on the id.

```
public async Task<int> GetReportCountXmonths(string name, int months)
{
    var limit = new ObjectId(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-(months)), 0, 1, 2);

    await GetCollection<Clients>()
        .Find(Builders<Clients>.Filter.Eq(d => d.name, name) 
            & Builders<Clients>.Filter.Gte(f => f.Id, limit)
        .CountDocumentsAsync();
}
```